# How to make content transition with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

Upon transaction from fragment A to B, I'd like some specific view of fragment B to move from point X to point Y. That should be possible to achieve using content transition: [Frament.setEnterTransition(Object transition)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setEnterTransition(java.lang.Object)). I don't understand what should I pass to `setEnterTransition(Object transition)` in order to tell the specific view of B to animate in a specific way.

A lot can be found on the web but it mostly refers to shared element transition, I can't find any help with content transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this as your fragment's layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:background="@android:color/white"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
            android:id="@+id/shared_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:background="#812432"/>

    <View
            android:id="@+id/non_shared_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:background="#fff53f"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And you perform this from your first fragment, that initiates opening of second fragment:

```
Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
set.addTransition(slide);
set.addTarget(R.id.shared_view);
Fragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
secondFragment.setEnterTransition(set);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.contentPanel, secondFragment)
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
```

You'll see, that `shared_view` will slide from left to it's initial position, while `non_shared_view` will stay in it's place.

[image]

[Source code](http://rgho.st/6tVBWbs87).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a follow-up question :) I'd like my view to travel along a custom path. I have TransitionSet object with PathMotion specified, how do I specify the point on the screen to start the animation from. TransitionSet doesn't seem to have a setter for that.

Comment: You have to create your own transition and override `captureStartValues()`.

Answer (score 0):

Content Transitions in explained in following website http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-content-transitions-in-depth-part2.html